# Numbered results list and maintain position number if times are equal

Tags: php, loops

I have a results table which I iterate over and then echo out.

```
$c = 1;
foreach ($results as $result) {
    $r .= '<tr>'
    . '<th scope="row">' . ($time === $result['time']? $c - 1 : $c)  . '</th>'
    . '<td>' . $result['name'] . '</td>'
    . '<td>' . $result['time'] . ' </td>'
    . '<td>' . $result['points'] . ' </td>'
    . '</tr>';

    $time = $result['time'];
    $c++;
}
```

I compare the current time with the previous result time and display the count the same if they match.
e.g.
1. Tom  0.33
2. Ben  0.34
2. Carl 0.34
4. Des  0.35
5. Dave 0.36

But what if Des had also got 0.34? It would display count 3 and it should stay on 2.

Any ideas how to solve this without getting too complex?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$c = 1;
$lastC = $c;
foreach ($results as $result) {

    if ($time === $result['time']) {
        $place = $lastC;
    } else {
        $place = $c;
        $lastC = $c;
    }

    $r .= '<tr>'
    . '<th scope="row">' . $place  . '</th>'
    . '<td>' . $result['name'] . '</td>'
    . '<td>' . $result['time'] . ' </td>'
    . '<td>' . $result['points'] . ' </td>'
    . '</tr>';

    $time = $result['time'];
    $c++;
}
```

Comment: Would this work if there were multiple runs of people with the same time? I feel like lastC would lag behind (I could be wrong)

Answer (score 1):

Its because you have it only decrementing by 1.

```
$c - 1
```

You would want a counter like you have, but a current row.  Something like

```
$c = 1;
$curr = $c;
foreach( $results as $result){
  if($time === $result['time']){
    use $curr;
  }else{
    use $c;
    $curr = $c + 1;
  }
  $c++;
}
```

but if you move the $c++, you can tie it in with with $curr, like

```
$c++;
$curr = $c;
```

Comment: Of course. I should have thought of that. You just didn't need to increment $c by one in the else statement hence giving the answer to @Tro.

Comment: np.  I shouldve properly formatted it such that it follows your answer, but at least i was of some assistnace to you. :)  Have a great day

Answer (score 0):

```
function compare($one, $two)
{
    $a = $one['time'];
    $b = $two['time'];

    if ($a == $b) {
        return 0;
    }

    return ($a < $b) ? -1 : +1;
}


$array = array(
    array('name' => 'Tom', 'time' => '0.33', 'points' => 1),
    array('name' => 'Ben', 'time' => '0.36', 'points' => 1),
    array('name' => 'Carl', 'time' => '0.35', 'points' => 1),
    array('name' => 'Des', 'time' => '0.33', 'points' => 1),
    array('name' => 'Dave', 'time' => '0.34', 'points' => 1)
);

usort($array, 'compare');

print_r($array);
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure this doesn't answer the question. I'd guess the asker's already got a sorting mechanism in place before the code they wanted help with

Answer (score -1):

you do a on time math operation in your short if. you have to make the result permanent:

```
$c = 1;
foreach ($results as $result) {
    if($time === $result['time'])
      $c--;
    $r .= '<tr>'
    . '<th scope="row">' . $c  . '</th>'
    . '<td>' . $result['name'] . '</td>'
    . '<td>' . $result['time'] . ' </td>'
    . '<td>' . $result['points'] . ' </td>'
    . '</tr>';

    $time = $result['time'];
    $c++;
}
```

Comment: uh, sorry. that's my fault. I thought this would be the desired result